# Issue with imaskJS data formatting forward slashes

Tags: javascript, npm, imaskjs

I've tested this on the frontend of the imask (https://imask.js.org/) website, and can confirm that when you use a forward slash for the date formatting it refuses to allow the final digit of the date.

I have tried using:

```
IMask(
      field,
      {
        mask: Date,
        pattern: 'd{\/]}`m{\/}`Y',
        min: new Date(1990, 0, 1),
        max: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
        lazy: false
    });

IMask(
      field,
      {
        mask: Date,
        pattern: 'd{/]}`m{/}`Y',
        min: new Date(1990, 0, 1),
        max: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
        lazy: false
    });

IMask(
      field,
      {
        mask: Date,
        pattern: 'd/m/Y',
        min: new Date(1990, 0, 1),
        max: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
        lazy: false
    });
```

Anything but forward slashes works.

Answer (score 1):

Seems i found an answer.

```
IMask(
  date_of_birth_fields[i],
  {
    mask: Date,
    pattern: 'd/`m/`Y',
    format: function (date) {
      var day = date.getDate();
      var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
      var year = date.getFullYear();
  
      if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;
      if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
  
      return [day, month, year].join('/');
    },
    // define str -> date convertion
    parse: function (str) {
      var yearMonthDay = str.split('/');
      return new Date(yearMonthDay[2], yearMonthDay[1] - 1, yearMonthDay[0]);
    },
    min: new Date(1980, 0, 1),
    max: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
    lazy: false,
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The docs state that "if you set pattern option, then you also have to provide format and parse options".
I was struggling finding this information
https://imask.js.org/guide.html#masked-date

Comment: as document said because you change the pattern order you must use parse function and because new date function get index of the month you should pass index of the month to new date value not the same month value , this is why you must do month value - 1